# Android virtual keyboard pop-up issue on focus

Tags: keyboard, dolphin-browser, html5

We are using a web app (built for desktop) in Android tablet (Motorola ET1). Issue is that android soft keyboard is popping up whenever focus goes to a text box.

On page load, focus is set to the text box but keyboard is not popping on page load. Users scan input data using tablet's scanner into this text box, we take scanned input and submit to the server. If the transaction is successful, text box gets cleared and focus is set in this text box to scan next input. when focus is set this time, android keyboard is popping up.

I tried using blur to prevent keyboard popup, it prevents keyboard from popping up but focus is not in that text box so user cannot scan the input data.

As an option, I installed null keyboard on Android tablet and provided jquery keyboard (https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/wiki) to enter input data if they want to enter data manually. This option seems to work technically but this shuts off the keyboard for entire tablet and users have other apps on the tablet so they are not happy with this solution.

We are using dolphin browser in this tablet. Dolphin has cordova plugin to get an access to device's native functions. But I don't see anything related to keyboard. Also I am not finding any reference in HTML5 documentation also.

Can you please suggest if there is any solution to this ? Please note that our application is a standard webapp and not built as Android app. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Please read the [FAQ] as to why this is voted-to-close because its a development related question. Would be better fit to post at [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: I think this question is okay for here. "How to keep the keyboard from popping up when I tap on a web form input field" is something an end-user might want help with.

Comment: @t0mm13b I have posted it on StackOverFlow as well, but no reponse yet.